# SevenZipSharp: Aborting In ProgressCompression

Tags: sevenzipsharp

Using SevenZipSharp wrapper has anyone succeeded in aborting an in-progress compression? I used:

```
FileCompressionStarted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SevenZip.FileNameEventArgs)
```

to see some activity and tried:

```
e.cancel = true
```

but nothing happened. Compression continues working until all files are packed. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide more information about your issue.

Comment: ok, so I use this wrapper to pack several files into 7z format (LZMA) and works fine. The problem is when I pass large number of files to compressor, operation can take long especially on non-compressable files and I may need to ABORT operation. So naturally, in the event thrown by library state above, e.cancel should work :(

Answer (score 0):

resolved and explained in other forum, please see link, thanks everyone

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?697661-RESOLVED-SevenZipSharp-aborting-compression&p=4272389#post4272389

PS. Just to have solution here, in case anyone needs

**e.cancel** isn't treated well in library because (like I expected) when I set **e.cancel = true** once, the library **may not catch this request**. I'm not sure this is sevenzipsharp.dll problem or 7z.dll but in code posted, when many clicks hits to my Abort button, finally, library aborted compression !!!

So implementation needs to be:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    abort = True
    console.addLine("Abort requested...")
End Sub

Private Sub fFileCompressionStarted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SevenZip.FileNameEventArgs)

    Dim s As String = ""
    If abort Then
        e.Cancel = True
        s = " aborted"
    End If

    console.addLine("[CompressionStarted event] e.Filename = " + e.FileName + ", e.PercentDone = " + e.PercentDone.ToString + s)



End Sub

Public Sub fCompressionFinished(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    console.addLine("[CompressionFinished event]")
    abort = False
End Sub
```

Best regards,
Edouard Gora, YO3HCV

Comment: You should not answer your question just to leave messages. People will help you if they can even without these kind of requests!